# Clear icon inside ui.bootstrap.typeahead

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using an angular UI typeahead from [Angular bootstrap UI](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead)

I would like to be able to clear the selection using an icon in the textbox like below

```
--------------------------------------------------
|                                               X|
--------------------------------------------------
```

I have tried using input type search but that didn't work.
my code:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search"
uib-typeahead="eachCatigory in catigories | limitTo:8"/>
```

Any suggestions are great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://plnkr.co/edit/e8KUEKNkKZTOVa4DU3oN?p=preview

```
<div class='input-group'>
  <input type="text"
         ng-model="selected"
         uib-typeahead="state for state in states"
         class="form-control" />
  <span class="input-group-addon"
        ng-click="selected=''">
    X
  </span>
</div>
```

Modified version that has the X just overlaid on the text box (using relative and absolute positioning)

http://plnkr.co/edit/kBq0U2D5i8CyNwykDUcj?p=preview

Comment: that one will work if I cannot get it actually inside the textbox.

Comment: @user3648646 you can certainly shim it over the top using some absolutely positioned element (set the right and top values for an absolutely positioned element that comes before it, but I figured go the less hacky route)

Comment: @user3648646 I added another plnkr showing how you can do it with absolute positioning